# finding integer and string from split sentence

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, python-3.x

I need to split this string:

```
"We shall win 100 dollars in the next 2 years"
```

and return a tuple with a list of integers and strings `([100,2],[We,shall,win,dollars,in,the,next,years])`.

My attempts so far:

```
lst_int =[]
    lst_str =[]
    tup_com =(lst_int,lst_str)
    words = input_string.split()
    for i in words:
        if i == int():
            lst_int.append(i)
        elif i != int():
            lst_str.append(i)
    return tup_com
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with simple regex

```
import re
s = "We shall win 100 dollars in the next 2 years"

t = (re.findall("[0-9]+",s),re.findall("[a-zA-Z]+",s))
```

Comment: another great approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using several methods:

1) checking `isdigit`:

```
sentence = "We shall win 100 dollars in the next 2 years"

str_list=[]
int_list=[]
for word in sentence.split():
   if word.isdigit():
      int_list.append(int(word))  # cast at the same time
   else:
      str_list.append(word)
```

Problem: if number is negative, you have to check for numbers containing minus sign, space chars, which are still considered valid numbers makes it more complicated for `isdigit`. This could lead you to a regex, which is more complex and opens pandora's box on integer parsing using regex... (and I'm not even mentionning floating point numbers)

2) rely on python integer parsing:

```
str_list=[]
int_list=[]
for word in sentence.split():
    try:
        int_list.append(int(word))
    except ValueError:
        str_list.append(word)
```

A tad slower because of exception handling, but works fine in all cases, and could even be generalized for floats.

Comment: Thank you very much for the excellent explanation. Merci beaucoup Monsieur!

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved if you tweak your condition a bit. `i == int()` doesn't really do what you think; `int()` returns `0` so you're essentially continuously checking if `i == 0` which, will always be `False` (causing everything to be appended to `lst_str`.

Instead, use `str.isdigit` in your `for` loop as so:

```
if i.isdigit():
    lst_int.append(i)
else:
    lst_str.append(i)
```

`str.isdigit` goes through the characters in the string you supply and evaluates if they are all digits (and the string is non-empty).

Then, `tup_com` results in:

```
(['100', '2'], ['We', 'shall', 'win', 'dollars', 'in', 'the', 'next', 'years'])
```

As an aside, you don't need `tup_com` here, simply return the lists separated by a comma and a tuple is created that contains them.

That is:

```
return lst_int, lst_str
```